# Need help in scheme programming

Tags: list, lambda, functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I want the program to count how many times a particular sub-string has been found in an expression.I wrote the following code but I'm not getting the anticipated output.

```
(define (count-occurrences s slist)
    (if (null? slist)
            0
        (+ (count-occurrences-in-s-sexp s (car slist))
           (count-occurrences s (cdr slist)))))

(define (count-occurrences-in-s-sexp s sexp)
    (if (symbol? sexp)
            (if (eqv? sexp s) 1 0)
        (count-occurrences s sexp)))

Input: (count-occur '(a x) '((x y z) x (z (a x) y)) )
Output: 0
Expected O/p : 1

Input: (count-occur 'x '((x y z) x (z (a x) y)))
Output: 3
Expected O/p : 3
```

When I'm giving an input of list.I am not getting the expected output.Can anyone help me :/

Comment: What *is* the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `equal?` instead of `eqv?` to determine if two lists are the same.

Comment: It is still the same. Its not comparing the list :( . I am getting zero